# Отслеживание файлов на удаленном сервере

Tags: c#, файлы, сервер, rdp

Приветствую знатоки.

Есть вопрос, как можно организовать отслеживание изменений файлов на удаленном сервере в локальной сети.

Есть сервант, логин и пас от него. Там с переодичностью вываливаются новые файлы с определенной структурой именования. Нужно организовать отслеживание появления файлов в "онлайн" режиме, с определением веса файла.

Если есть ссылки или идеи, поделитесь пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В .NET есть класс `System.IO.FileSystemWatcher`, который позволяет отслеживать изменения в файлах и вложенных каталогах заданного каталога. Можно создать компонент, который будет следить за файлами на локальном компьютере, на сетевых дисках или на удаленном компьютере (из [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx)).
У класса есть события, названия которых говорят сами за себя (`Created`, `Changed` и т.д.). Вам остается лишь определиться, как организовать такое отслеживание:

1. Удаленно. Программа следит за каталогом на удаленном компьютере и выполняет какие-то действия по определенным событиям.
2. Локально. Программа запускается на сервере и следит за нужным каталогом. В этом случае по определенным событиям ей придется делать какие-то дополнительные запросы для нотификации.

Answer (score 0):

Если это web-приложение и если вся структура(пути, размер, дата. и т.д.) файлов и их публикация организованна на уровне БД, то так же на уровне БД и реализовывать отслеживание публикации файлов...

Если вы хотите организовать полухацкерское ПО то вам нужно копаться в протоколах TCP/IP выбирать вариант наименьшего сопротивления по запуску и отслеживанию внутрисетевого паука(бота) который бы и реализовывал задачу, ну и вам тут C# скорее не помощник...

Comment: никаких хацкеров. Обычное приложение сканирующее наличие файлов. Всё официально. Функционал типа заббикс, если файл появился и имеет размер - сообщить об этом